# How was Peter a.k.a. Spider-Man able to move his hands in his astral form?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-no-way-home

At one point in the film, Spider-Man and Doctor Strange fight over the spell box that has the ability to send all of the multiverse villains back to their respective timelines.

However, at one point in the battle Strange separates Parker from his physical body and attempts to take the box from his hand. Instead, even though Parker’s astral form is separated from his body, his physical body is still moving the box away from Strange’s reach. *Strange goes as far as noting that Parker shouldn’t be able to do that.*

---

How was he able to do that? As we have seen earlier no one is capable to do that not even Dr. Strange (according to movies).

Answer (score 6):

This is not an authoritative answer but rather a plausible explanation. I got it from [this Screen Rant video](https://youtu.be/ecmWv06K5hc).

It is because Spider-Man has a spider sense (aka his tingle) as one of his powers. This power is in his body, not his soul, and allows the body to sense danger and thus react accordingly. In other words it is a super-powered instinct that other beings who have been separated from their soul wouldn’t have.

Comment: Although Peter's abilities are certainly super, it seems worth noting that normal human beings in real life also have reflexes that allow their body to avoid danger without conscious thought. If you touch something hot, your hand recoils before you're even consciously aware that it's being burnt, for example. My body wouldn't realize that a wizard trying to grab a macguffin was a problem, though.

Answer (score 3):

## His Spidey sense was tingling.

If you look at the scene where he is floating around, you can see wiggly lines similar to his classic spidey sense.

[image]

Spiderman powers are often associated with spiderman in the form of the [spider totem](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Totems) and the web of [reality](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Web_of_Life_and_Destiny) so it's reasonable them giving his spidey sense enough mystical mojo to still function when his body is disconnected from his soul.

This may link in with the upcoming comic spiderverse films, [across the spiderverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man:_Across_the_Spider-Verse_(Part_One)). A popular villain is [Morlun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morlun), who hunts and eats Spidemen across the multiverse for their mystical mojo.

Answer (score 0):

> As we have seen earlier no one is capable to do that not even Dr. Strange

That's not entirely true.

> In the post-credits scene of the final episode of *WandaVision*, having increased her power by having absorbed Agatha Harkness' powers, Wanda is seen sitting on the porch of a cabin in the middle of nowhere. Wanda then gets up and walks inside, and the camera pans past her into a back room where she is actually sitting in her astral form, studying the Book of the Damned, while also having full control over her astral body at the same time.

It is not explicitly stated how she is able to do that, so we cannot as of yet draw any parallels to how Peter was able to retain minimal control of his body while in astral form, but it is at the very least worth noting that he is actually not the first one to show this ability.

If I had to guess, I would say that it has something to do with how he has the Spider Sense. That ability is, in and of itself, literally an out-of-body sense. So I would bet money on it having something to do with that.

Comment: That doesn't really explain why *Peter* was able to do so, so this seems to  be a comment on another answer rather than an answer in its own right.

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! If you want to hide a spoiler, you should preface it with a spoiler tag `>!`, as I've done in my edit. Merely adding a bunch of line breaks won't work, because they won't be preserved.